# Nginx refuses to listen on port 443

Tags: ssl, nginx, https, nginx-config

I am having an issue with nginx where it won't listen on port 443.

Listening on port 80 is fine. I have included a snippet of my config below:

```
server {
       listen 443 ssl default_server;
       listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;

       ssl on;
       ssl_certificate     /var/www/certs/server.pem;
       ssl_certificate_key /var/www/certs/server.key;

       server_name server;

       root /var/www/server;

       access_log /var/log/nginx/server/access.log;
       error_log  /var/log/nginx/server/error.log;

       index index.php;
}
```

not sure where I am going wrong. Everything I have checked shows that it should be working.

I am on Ubuntu 18.04 with nginx 1.14.0
there is no firewall on the system, nor between myself and the server.
I have checked the config several times with `nginx -t` and `systemctl reload`ed as well. no change, the port does not open for me.

Answer (score 0):

To configure an HTTPS server, the ssl parameter must be enabled on listening sockets in the server block, and the locations of the server certificate and private key files should be specified:

```
server {
listen              443 ssl;
server_name         www.example.com;
ssl_certificate     www.example.com.crt;
ssl_certificate_key www.example.com.key;
ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
...
```

}

A single HTTP/HTTPS server
It is possible to configure a single server that handles both HTTP and HTTPS requests:

```
server {
listen              80;
listen              443 ssl;
server_name         www.example.com;
ssl_certificate     www.example.com.crt;
ssl_certificate_key www.example.com.key;
...
```

}

Prior to 0.7.14 SSL could not be enabled selectively for individual listening sockets, as shown above. SSL could only be enabled for the entire server using the ssl directive, making it impossible to set up a single HTTP/HTTPS server. The ssl parameter of the listen directive was added to solve this issue. The use of the ssl directive in modern versions is thus discouraged.

Name-based HTTPS servers
A common issue arises when configuring two or more HTTPS servers listening on a single IP address:

```
server {
listen          443 ssl;
server_name     www.example.com;
ssl_certificate www.example.com.crt;
...
```

}

```
server {
listen          443 ssl;
server_name     www.example.org;
ssl_certificate www.example.org.crt;
...
```

}

Comment: if you read my question, it included a partial of my config, which includes the ssl directive, cert-pem, and key.

Comment: listen 443 ssl default_server;
       listen [::]:443 ssl default_server; You are also doing this twice. Is there a reason for that?  Try listen 443 ssl;

Comment: those are there to catch both ipv4 and ipv6.

Answer (score 0):

Add these server blocks.

This is to redirect http to https

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name example.com; 
   location / {
          return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
   }
}
```

Your main block with ssl

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl ;
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; 
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;  
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name example.com; 
    location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5003; // Your port goes here
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
}
```

Also check if the ports are open